# How to avoid a search auto suggestion list box that contains previously searched items which triggers on a click in search box

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

How to prevent an  auto suggestion search list box that contains previously searched items which triggers initially on a click in search box. How to prevent this browser property through codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autocomplete="off"` on your search box.